# Current page id returns the incorrect value

Tags: globals

I need to capture the current page id, execute some conditional script in footer, in my own plugin function hooks to `wp_footer`.

Here is my plugin code, but page id returning wrong value?

```
<?php
/*
  Plugin Name: My Plugin
  Author:  GS
  Version: 1.1
*/
Function footer_page_id()
{
  global $post;
  echo '<div> page_id:'.$post->ID.'</div>';// output wrong value
  global $wp_query;      
  echo 'page_id:'.get_the_ID();// output wrong value
  echo 'post_id:'.$wp_query->post->ID; // output wrong value
  echo 'page_id:'.$wp_query->get_queried_object_id(); // output always 0
  echo'</br>';exit;
}
 add_action('wp_footer', ' footer_page_id ');
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may need to reset the `$wp_query` — try this: add `wp_reset_query();` after the `global $post;`.

Answer (score 1):

To get the current page ID outside of The Loop, you need to use `get_queried_object_id();` (`$wp_query->` is unnecessary).

However, this will only work when you are viewing a single Page (so anything under *Pages > All Pages* in the back-end).

If you are viewing the blog, an archive, or a category it will not be a valid page ID. On categories it will return the category ID, but on archives or the blog it will not have a value because those things do not have an ID.

If your theme or another plugin uses `query_posts()`, this could interfere with this function. Using `wp_reset_query()` will fix this, but whichever theme or plugin is running `query_posts()` should be doing this.

If *you* are using `query_posts()`, *don't*. Use a custom query with `new WP_Query()` or `get_posts()`.

Answer (score 1):

for above requirement you can rewrite the code like this

```
function footer_page_id()
{
  global $post;
  echo '<div> page_id:'.$post->ID.'</div>';
 // remaining codes here

}
 add_action('wp_footer', 'footer_page_id');
```

Please note that inorder to check the value of a variable inside a wordpress function please use debug log technique.

First enable debugging as per wordpress official tutorial https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Then you can find  debugg.log file inside **wp-content** folder

```
function footer_page_id()
{
  global $post;
  echo '<div> page_id:'.$post->ID.'</div>';// output wrong value
  error_log(print_r($post->ID,true));


}
 add_action('wp_footer', 'footer_page_id');
```

Like this you can check the variable values in plugin.